# Can a mangekyou sharingan user awake Eternel Mangekyou, by only transplanting a pair of Normal Sharingans, or does it need a pair of MS?

Tags: naruto

I know they can restore their eyesight by transplanting any kind of Sharingan, but can they also activate EMS from only normal sharingans? (not MS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they cannot. It is in the manga and in the [wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan).

> ...usage of the Mangekyō Sharingan's abilities can cause a great strain on the user...it can cause considerable damage to their being, leaving the body in agonising pain and causing deterioration to their vision until eventually over-usage leaves them blind. Their vision can be restored by transplanting the Mangekyō Sharingan of an Uchiha with strong blood ties — ideally a sibling — thus awakening the so-called Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan

As far as I know, *there have been no cases where Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan awakened simply by transplanting 'normal' Sharingan eyes unto a Mangekyo Sharingan user*.

Comment: But, can an uchiha awaken MS again on a normal omplented sharingan ? :D